# Aggrid add button Apply and Reset to all Filter toolpanel

Tags: ag-grid

As i see when i change any filter value it sends immediate changed filter data.

I need to have two buttons "Apply" & "Reset" at the bottom of filter toolPanel.
On "Apply" it will do backend call with all filters data.
On "Reset" it will reset all filters.

Is it possible or i need to implement own custom ToolPanel ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/).

Answer (score 1):

AG Grid Allows you the ability to render Apply, Clear, Reset and Cancel Buttons on AG Grid Filters. You can use them like below in `filterParams`.

```
    filterParams:{
    buttons: ['clear', 'apply']
    }
```

try this .
[example from AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/grid-vanilla.php?section=javascript-grid-filter-provided&example=buttons-and-filter-events&generated=1&clientside=1&setfilter=1&menu=1&columnpanel=1&enterprise=1&grid=%7B%22noStyle%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3Atrue%7D)